# Does KafkaConsumer API 0.9 has solution to below scenario?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am relatively new to Kafka. I have started developing application using Kafka 0.9, where multiple modules are interacting using Kafka topic.

I am particularly stuck with one scenario, scenario is as follows:

There are two modules in system say Module 1 and Module 2. These two modules interact with each other over Kafka. Module 1 keeps on creating multiple topics dynamically and also produces messages and pushes them to multiple topics based on certain condition. Now Module 2 will be in sleep mode through out application's life cycle. Module 2 will consume data only when any request comes to Module 2 to consume data from specific topic. After consuming data Module 2 will again go back to sleep mode.

I checked many portal's but couldn't find logical solution to this.

How to implement this scenario in Kafka 0.9. Small example code snippet in Java will be helpful.

Comment: Why do you think this will not work?  This is the base use case for Kafka.  Try it out and ask questions here when you run into problems.

Comment: There's no reason it wouldn't work, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how all (message) queues behave.
But, considering how you described your problem, I'm actually not sure that you need Kafka.

What exactly are these modules of yours? Application modules?
Can you roughly specify the load you're expecting (e.g. msgs/day)?

Comment: They are two independent parts of system. One processes data and forwards it to topic for consumer to consume it. But consumer will invoke these data whenever user of system asks for data. Based on user's request, consumer will consume data from respective topic.

Expected Data load is 1Million messages per day.

Comment: OK, roger that. Million messages per day are peanuts and you could use any "non-big-data" message queue, but OK, let's say that you're set on Kafka. Are you now ready to state your problem? What exactly did you do and where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I resolved my problem on last Friday. I am able to setup and run above mentioned scenario successfully using Kafka's pause and resume methods of consumer Api.

Thanks for all your interest to resolve my query. :)